# How to delete all the files stored in the protected storage

Tags: android, performance

I have created a dir in my protected app storage and saved couple of image files :

```
cacheDir = context.getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Is there a way to clear all the content of the protected storage files, **without** saving each file path and then deleting them one by one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
       if( path.exists() ) {
       File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (files == null) {
         return true;
        }
       for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
         deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
        else {
          files[i].delete();
        }
     }
   }
  return( path.delete() );
}
```

Comment: So I should keep a track of all the directories ?

But when I do 'clear cache' from the app settings does it delete all the files and directories ?

Comment: No , You just need to keep track of your app dir. which is cache_dir.getAbsolutePath(). Clear Cache will remove cached files , these files and directories will be deleted when you uninstall the application

Comment: ok thanks for the answer.

i'm giving you a +1 for the answer, I will accept it later if there won't be a better answers.